# MS Access SQL query within VBA code

Tags: vba, ms-access

I need a second set of eyes on this SQL query embedded in the VBA code. I'm making an MS Access app that returns a dataset based on the to & from date criteria set by the user in the specific date picker boxes.  The sql query that you see actually has been tested statically within MS Access query design view.  I tested it with actual dates where you see the Me.from_filter and Me.to_filter.  It worked perfectly!  If you chose something like from 1/1/2015 to 5/1/2015 it returns columns of all the months you need.  Perfect.  Now when I embed it in the VBA code and assign it to a control variable, I get the "Run-time error '2342': A RunSQL action requires an argument consisting of an SQL statement."  Can someone please eyeball this and tell me what might be wrong?

```
Option Compare Database
Option Explicit
Dim strSQL As String


Private Sub Command0_Click()
If IsNull(Me.from_filter) Or IsNull(Me.to_filter) Then
    MsgBox "You have not entered a start date or end date"
Else
    strSQL = "TRANSFORM Sum(dbo_ASSET_HISTORY.MARKET_VALUE) AS SumOfMARKET_VALUE " _
            & "SELECT [dbo_FIRM]![NAME] AS [FIRM NAME], dbo_FUND.CUSIP, dbo_FUND.FUND_NAME, dbo_FUND.PRODUCT_NAME " _
            & "FROM (dbo_ASSET_HISTORY INNER JOIN dbo_FIRM ON dbo_ASSET_HISTORY.FIRM_ID = dbo_FIRM.FIRM_ID) INNER JOIN dbo_FUND ON dbo_ASSET_HISTORY.FUND = dbo_FUND.FUND " _
            & "WHERE (((dbo_FIRM.Name) Like 'Voya F*') And ((dbo_ASSET_HISTORY.PROCESS_DATE) >= #" & Me.from_filter & "# And (dbo_ASSET_HISTORY.PROCESS_DATE) <= #" & Me.to_filter & "#)) " _
            & "GROUP BY [dbo_FIRM]![NAME], dbo_FUND.CUSIP, dbo_FUND.FUND_NAME, dbo_FUND.PRODUCT_NAME " _
            & "PIVOT [dbo_ASSET_HISTORY]![ASSET_YEAR] & '-' & [dbo_ASSET_HISTORY]![ASSET_MONTH];"
    DoCmd.RunSQL (strSQL)

End If
End Sub
```

Answer (score 3):

RunSQL is for running action queries like update, insert, select into, delete, etc as per Microsoft definition https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/office/ff194626.aspx , you should probably use OpenQuery or similar to run your query.

Comment: Or     CurrentDB.Execute strSQL